# Позиционирование absolute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
 $('.product__item').hover(function () {
        $(this).css({
            overflow:'visible'
        })

        $(this).children('.product__add').css({
            display:'flex'
        })
    }, function () {
        $(this).css({
            overflow:'hidden'
        })

        $(this).children('.product__add').css({
            display:'none'
        })
    });
```

```css
.product {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.product__item {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.product__block {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.product__p {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}
.product__add {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
  z-index: 4;
}
.product__add-pos {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="owl__products" class="product">
            <div class="product__item">
                <div class="product__block product__block-pos">
                        <div class="product__p"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__add product__add-pos"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product__item">
                <div class="product__block product__block-pos">
                    <div class="product__p"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__add product__add-pos"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product__item">
                <div class="product__block product__block-pos">
                    <div class="product__p"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__add product__add-pos"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product__item">
                <div class="product__block product__block-pos">
                    <div class="product__p"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__add product__add-pos"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product__item">
                <div class="product__block product__block-pos">
                    <div class="product__p"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__add product__add-pos"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/53638.html

Мне нужно сделать подобный блок как в карусели на главной странице этого сайта. То есть, что бы был блок с описанием товара `product__p` и при наведении на него показывалась дополнительная информация о товаре `product__add`, НО при этом этот дополнительный блок не должен влиять на блоки вокруг (что бы был `position: absolute;`) . Я сделал это демо, оно рабочее, но я в нем "не уверен", тк я указал `position: absolute;`  для дополнительного блока и не указал ему top, left, right или bottom, работает все нормально `product__add` появляется под (после)  `product__p`. Но есть ли это нормальным, или лучше как то по другому сделать?

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном Вами [примере](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/53638.html) тот же принцип используется (absolute).
Вполне нормальное решение.

```css
.product {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.product__item {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
.product__block {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.product__p {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}
.product__add {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
  z-index: 4;
}

.product__add-pos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.product__item:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
.product__item:hover .product__add-pos {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="product__item">
                <div class="product__block product__block-pos">
                        <div class="product__p"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__add product__add-pos"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product__item">
                <div class="product__block product__block-pos">
                    <div class="product__p"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__add product__add-pos"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product__item">
                <div class="product__block product__block-pos">
                    <div class="product__p"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__add product__add-pos"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product__item">
                <div class="product__block product__block-pos">
                    <div class="product__p"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__add product__add-pos"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product__item">
                <div class="product__block product__block-pos">
                    <div class="product__p"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__add product__add-pos"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
```